# Add string to util.List[_]

Tags: scala

I am trying to override a Java method in Scala.

This is the method in the Java Class:

```
public void foo(List bar) {}
```

And this is the Method in Scala:

```
override def foo(bar: util.List[_]) {
    bar :+ "Text"
    bar.add("Text")
}
```

Both produce the following compiler Error:

```
Error:(78, 17) type mismatch;
found   : String("Text")
required: _$1
bar.add("Text")

Error:(78, 13) value :+ is not a member of java.util.List[_$1]
bar:+ "Text"
```

How can I add a String to this list?

Answer (score 4):

The first attempt is easy to address; `java.util.List` just doesn't have a method called `:+`.<sup>1</sup>

For the second attempt: I think what you're missing is that `List[_]` is not the same as `List[Any]`.<sup>2</sup> If you change the type to `List[Any]`,<sup>3</sup> you can add anything to it.

```
def foo(bar: java.util.List[Any]): Unit = bar.add("Text")
```

If you can't change the signature, you can do a cast.<sup>4</sup>

```
override def foo(bar: java.util.List[_]): Unit =
  bar.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[Any]].add("Text")
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It would be crazy if it did, since you couldn't even call that method from Java code.

<sup>2</sup> `List[_]` means a `List` of *an unspecified type*. So, for instance, `bar` could be a `List[Integer]`, therefore it's a good thing that `bar.add("Text")` doesn't compile, because that wouldn't make any sense.

<sup>3</sup> But in general, if you find yourself using `Any`, you should rethink your design.

<sup>4</sup> But, again, bear in mind that this is terrible.

Comment: This seems to prevent the method from overriding the Java method.

Comment: What's the Java method signature? Does `List[Object]` work?

Comment: The Problem is that I can't modify the Java method in any way. But `asInstanceOf` seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you modify the Java signature - What I mean to ask is, does the override work if you change the Scala type from `List[_]` to `List[Object]`?

Answer (score 0):

Scala doesn't permit you to use unchecked types like that, you have to fully specify all type arguments in this position. The error about `:+` is because you are passing a java list and not a scala list.

```
override def foo(bar: java.util.List[String]): Unit = {
  bar.add("Text") 
}
```

Comment: "Scala doesn't permit you to use unchecked types like that" - Doesn't it? `def foo(bar: List[_]) = bar(0)` seems to work fine.

Comment: @ChrisMartin you can specify them in certain places but you can't do everything with them as you can in java. In this case you can't access any type-dependent methods when unspecified